# Reset Ubuntu server password remotely

Tags: server, password, root

my friend is hosting a Minecraft Server for me. I wanted to update some plugins, I SSH into the server. But then I relieved I forgot the root password. I asked my friend, and he forgot too! I was wondering how I could reset it remotely.

Comment: Do you guys have sudo permissions? If so use `sudo passwd root`.

Comment: Root is the only account on there

Comment: Please [edit] the  output of `lsb_release` on the Ubuntu server with only the root account into your question. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: @ElderGeek If they could log in to the server with only that root account, they wouldn't have forgotten their password and wouldn't have a problem...

Comment: @ByteCommander that's true. I'm trying to parse the concept of having a server with only a root account period. Color me skeptical.

Comment: Unless you have some sort of BMC/VSP/Console ports to that server, you will have to make password changes physically on the server.  If you could change it remotely that would be a security violation and anybody could get right into your server at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can fortunately *not* log in remotely to a server without knowing the account password (or having SSH-keys set up).

Just imagine what happened if there was a way to bypass authentication on any arbitrary server connected to the internet and log in as root (or admin account with `sudo` permissions, doesn't matter). Looking at the issue this way makes it clear that such a thing may not be possible.

You can only reset a forgotten root password if you have physical access, which gives you the option to boot the system in recovery mode and drop to a root shell, as described in [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/24006/367990)